# Formation of a hydrogen atom from a proton and electron - detailed quantitative description

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, atomic-physics

Suppose a region of empty space, to which we add one proton and one electron, initially separated by a distance on the order of centimeters, and as close to "at rest" in the center-of-mass frame as we can practically achieve.

They will of course attract each other and combine into a hydrogen atom, emitting at least one photon in the process.  I'd like to understand this process in detail.  Specifically: for an initial separation this large, it seems likely that the system will not emit just one photon and go directly to the <sup>1</sup>H ground state, because that photon would be very energetic.  Instead there would be some number of bremsstrahlung interactions, followed by atomic orbital transitions, before reaching the ground state.

- How does one model this quantitatively?
- What would the typical number of emitted photons be, and what would their wavelengths be?
- How small can you make the initial separation before the most probable outcome is just one emitted photon?
- How does one draw the line between "bremsstrahlung" and "atomic orbital transition" in a system like this?
- What is the (ballpark) probability of something *else* happening, such as a weak interaction producing a neutron?  (That's the only possible "something else" I know of.  Are there others?)

Comment: I like this question, but I have a feeling it might be too broad. You might want to ask something more specific, or divide it into a couple of different questions.

Comment: What could possibly make you think that Quantum Mechanics turns off at some distance? In cold regions of space Rydberg atoms can be quite large, but they are still Quantum.

Comment: @Timaeus Is it seriously the case that classical electrodynamics is still a poor approximation for macroscopic initial separations in this hypothetical, or are you just being pedantic?

Comment: @zwol An atom could stay in a Rydberg state for an incredibly long time if isolated well enough. But the whole point is that specifying the *quantum* state is just like specifying the initial conditions. If the initial conditions indicate two objects orbit then they orbit. Different initial conditions would involve them rushing towards each other at increasing speeds. Your problem is that you act as if them being far apart means you don't **have** to specify the initial state. But the initial state affects *everything.* Just saying they are far apart doesn't tell us what we need to know.

Comment: @Timaeus OK, I think I see what you are saying, but I honestly don't see what is missing from my description.  The particles are at rest relative to each other at t=0 and they are separated by a distance on the order of centimeters: what remains to be specified?  I understand that the answer will be in some way a function of the exact separation distance, but I don't want an answer that is *specific* to one particular distance, because I want to understand the general case.

Comment: @zwol You claim you want to start with them having a known fixed position **and** a known fixed momentum. Do you see the problem? That would be like in Newtonian mechanics saying you want a particle to start out with an initial force and an initial acceleration that defy $F=ma$ you decided to break a law of physics as your alleged initial condition. The true initial conditions are totally different. They involve an initial *state*. In Newtonian mechanics you aren't free to adjust your acceleration. In QM you aren't free to adjust your velocity.

Comment: @Timaeus No, I still don't get it, because, again, we're starting in the classical limit (and if you are seriously claiming that centimeters of separation isn't enough to be in the classical limit, I want some numbers to back that up).  The mandatory uncertainty in position and momentum should be negligible on this scale at t=0.

Comment: @zwol There are many things called the classical limit. One of them is high Quantum numbers but a Rydberg atom is a high Quantum number and it doesn't have a fixed position. Another limit is a coarsening, you simply don't pay attention to the momentum and position as precisely and things look more classical to you. Other limits are quite specific, for instance when the quantum potential from Bohmian Mechanics is zero. When you say it's negligible is it because you choose to use imprecise measurement tools? The spread of positions measured from a Rydberg state is actually quite large.

Comment: @Timaeus I would think that the initial state here is something like a product of two localized wavepackets, one for the electron and one for the photon

Comment: @MitchellPorter Even if I assume you meant proton (rather than photon) there is still no theory ever proposed by any physicist where that would even be allowed, let alone be reasonable. In QFT you have an electron field and a proton field but their interaction would also require a photon field so you need at least three fields. And nonrelativistic QM requires a function from configuration space, not from physical space. So for a proton-electron system then for each moment in time you need a function from $\mathbb R^6$ into the joint spin state $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2.$

Comment: @Timaeus Yes, I meant proton... Basically I meant what you called coarsening.

Comment: Also that there should be no initial entanglement between the particles (or with the electromagnetic vacuum).

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I'm looking for an actual mathematical description of the process described in part 2 of the accepted answer to that question (i.e. how the initial state decays into the hydrogen atom ground state).

Comment: I'll retract thr close vote as soon as you clean up the question/ focus it using the linked Q

Answer (score 6):

Your question falls into an area of physics that is hard to understand - evolution of a system in time according to quantum-theoretic AND relativistic theory of matter.

In non-relativistic theory, one has the Schroedinger equation. The radiation due to system is NOT accounted for in the standard form of this equation. The equation conserves $\langle H \rangle$. The $\psi$ function will change in time but won't get to a point where it resembles atom of Bohr size. It will diffuse and change, but it will get bigger rather than smaller.

In a relativistic theory, there are many approaches and equations, but I do not know if there is some preferred way to model the process you imagine. I have never seen a paper that would try to simulate formation of bound state in time.

On a general level in QFT, one has the action principle for the quantum fields of electron and proton. One can derive equations restricting the fields from this principle and try to extract description of the system in time. But how to set up initial conditions for those fields that correspond to your picture of two particles 1m apart and how to visualize the evolving quantum fields, I do not know.

There is also a so-called Bethe-Salpeter equation that deals with bound states in a way close to QFT, but from the papers on it I've seen I got the impression that it is hard to find solutions and the authors themselves did not think it gives more insight beyond what can be extracted from the non-relativistic equations of Breit type with relativistic corrections (these still do not account for retardation and radiation).

To anyone reading this, if you know of some paper on this, please link it in a comment or post an answer, I would like to read it.